# How to close other panels when another one is opened in ng-bootstrap

Tags: angular, typescript, ng-bootstrap

I want to close all the collapse panel in my sidebar except the panel I clicked. I'm trying to achieve this behavior with ng-bootstrap collapse panel.

Example Code:

```
<ul class="sidebar">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" (click)="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed" [attr.aria-expanded]="!isCollapsed" aria-controls="collapse_1">Collapse1</a>
        <div class="collapse" id="collapse_1" [ngbCollapse]="isCollapsed">
            <ul class="nav">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link">Accordion</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link">Buttons</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" (click)="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed" [attr.aria-expanded]="!isCollapsed" aria-controls="collapse_2">Collapse2</a>
        <div class="collapse" id="collapse_2" [ngbCollapse]="isCollapsed">
            <ul class="nav">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link">Accordion</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link">Buttons</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix your model. A boolean `isCollapsed` can't possibly tell you **which** of N  panels is expanded.

Replace that boolean with a variable like `expandedPanelId`, which contains... the ID of the panel that is expanded.

Replace your `!isCollapsed` conditions by something like `expandedPanelId === 'collapse_2'`; and replace your click handlers with something like `expandedPanelId = 'collapse_2'`.

Comment: Got it !!. Thanks. But only one collapse panel should be opened at a time. The other one should close if another is one opened. And is there any way to add transitions while it's opening?

Answer (score 0):

For your case it is better to choose [Accordion](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/accordion/examples#static).
See [One open panel at a time](https://stackblitz.com/angular/ldxkqgqvqle)